# Making simple React handleChange() function into Higher Order Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-functions

```
function CheckoutForm({ onSubmit }) {
  const [shippingName, setShippingName] = useState("");
  
  function handleChange(func, e) {
    return function () {
      return func.call(null, e.target.value);
    };
  }
  
  return (
    <form>
      <div className="field">
        <label htmlFor="shipping-username">이름</label>
        <input
          id="shipping-username"
          type="text"
          name="shipping-username"
          autoComplete="off"
          value={shippingName}
          // onChange={(e) => setShippingName(e.target.value)} <--- ORIGINAL METHOD
          onChange={handleChange(setShippingName(e.target.value), e)} <--- MY QUESTION
        />
      </div>
    </form>
  )
}
```

While making a simple input field, I was curious if I could create a higher order handleChange function and reuse it for other inputs. I know there is a better way using computed property names, but just out of curiosity.

The error message I get from above code is that `e` is not defined and I am stuck here. Any advice is welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define an onChange handler like this:

`onChange={handleChange(setShippingName(e.target.value), e)}`

You're assigning the returned value of this handleChange call *as the handler*. You must therefore pass in your own values to handleChange, because it doesn't get called during the event -- e won't be defined at this point. It's only the resulting function that will receive e from the event.

So you could re-define handleChange with e as the argument to the inner function, like this:

```
  function handleChange(func) {
    return function (e) {
      return func.call(null, e.target.value);
    };
  }
```

And further down you can skip passing `e` (which woud be undefined anyway). Rather just do like this:

```
onChange={handleChange(setShippingName)}
```

...however, I think you can greatly simplify everything by just defining your handler inline like this:

```
onChange={(e) => setShippingName(e.target.value)}
```

^^ this is the way everyone does it.

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to make! I know this approach is not really the best but it's always fun to refactor something into a higher order functions ;)